# Is it possible to customise Azure AD login error messages?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

We have a Drupal site setup to login with Azure AD via a third party OpenID connect module.
This is linked to an Azure AD app registration in single tenant mode.
When a user visits the site whilst logged-in to an account that isn't in our tenant, they see an error message similar to this:

> Message:AADSTS50020: User account 'XXXXX@example.com' from identity provider 'https://sts.windows.net/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX/' does not exist in tenant 'TENANT NAME' and cannot access the application 'XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX'(SITE NAME) in that tenant. The account needs to be added as an external user in the tenant first. Sign out and sign in again with a different Azure Active Directory user account.

This message is completely incomprehensible to most of our users. I'd like to change it to something more meaningful such as

> Please login with an INSTITUTION NAME account to access this site e.g.: username@ourdomain.com

Is this something that can be configured within the Azure AD app registration? Or elsewhere in our tenancy configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of azure ad B2C you can create a custom error page using a [technical profile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/oauth2-error-technical-profile) based on [localization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids) or a custom policy error page. But **in case of  regular Azure AD (B2B)**, **there is no way to specify custom error messages** or error pages.

If there is any case where the error message is passed back to your application. there may be a possibility  to deal with it as you can configure through code as required but there isn't any guidance regarding error passed to backend .